# How in webix datatable columns of same category to be put adjacent while copying them

Tags: datatable, webix

In my Webix application, I have two datatables under separate tabs.

The columns of second table is same as first table with few extra columns.
While copying columns of first table to second, how can I align all editable columns at the end (on the extreme RHS) of the second datatable ?

Here is my snippet : https://webix.com/snippet/3ca44a3e

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around in JavaScript only by this following piece of code which rearranges the columns to put the editable ones at the end.

However, any better approach is most welcome:

```
var uneditable_cells = [];
var editable_cells = [];
  for (var i in mycols2) {
    var header = mycols2[i];    
    if(header.hasOwnProperty('editor')) {
      editable_cells.push(header);
    } else {
      uneditable_cells.push(header);
    }

  }

mycols2 =  uneditable_cells.concat(editable_cells);
```

Thanks.